# Implementing our own serializers in C# - tips and gotchas

Tags: c#, serialization, bit-manipulation

We probably need to write our own serializers for the classes in our (largeish) C# app - BinarySerializer is too slow and verbose, and [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) has problems with interface-based properties (of which we have loads).

Does anyone have any good tips and/or warnings? I suspect we should be using [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx), but we haven't done much bit-fiddling in C# yet, and any gotchas would be appreciated!

Similarly, does anyone know of a hand-rolled serializer with source code I could look at?

Comment: What are your timescales? I can try to round off v2 (but I've been saying that for too long already)

Comment: What about `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: @Marc: that would be great, but likely not fast enough for us, factoring in time for us to learn how to protobuf properly.

Comment: @Kent: As I understand it, 'DataContractSerializer' is slower and even more verbose than 'BinarySerializer'. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Tips / warnings? It can be a *serious* amount of code. I suggest it would be easier to write some *simple* code that transforms your existing model into a simple DTO that can be serialized trivially by your choice of existing serialization API. Having a DTO layer (separate to the domain entities) also allows much simpler maintenance - you can refactor your domain entities without breaking the serialized data.

The options for doing it yourself (keeping in mind that you emphasised that the model is fairly complex, and you aren't bit-fiddlers):

- write type-specific serialization manually; very easy to get wrong, very laborious
- write a general purpose library; crazy amounts of work solving all the edge cases

And that is **after** you have figured out a serialization format that works robustly, extensibly, and supports the scenarios you need (inheritance, etc).

Comment: We are not *C#* bit-fiddlers; In fact, I'm not any kind, but my colleagues certainly are.

Comment: I don't see how a DTO layer would speed up serialization. The problem presumably lies with the inherent wordyness of the .Net BinarySerializer, together with all the funky reflection and so on it must do to work generically. That would not change with a DTO layer, would it?

Comment: @Joel - well, perhaps if the DTO was designed to be suitable for protobuf-net ;p

Comment: Nice try ;) But I think the amount of effort needed for a DTO layer would be about the same as for a straightforward homebrew serialization... after all, if I am sending the data to another class, it might as well be via a StreamWriter or something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Type Convertors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx). We use them extensively with ViewState and they work great.

Comment: not to go on a tangent - but injecting serialized objects into ViewState is the most horrible thing i've heard today

Comment: Pete - Thats what ASP.net also does to maintain state accross post backs. Thats what ViewState is for.